# Como pasar una propiedad del state a otra componente

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

**Problema:** tengo una función que me realiza varias tarjetas de equipo, para no tener que hacer veinte distintas páginas he decidido crear una componente nueva de `react` igual para todos y que me permita así no tener que crear dichas páginas, el problema lo tengo al intentar pasar tanto con `Link` de `react-rooter-dom` como con la etiqueta `button`, ya que quiero pasar una propiedad del `state` especifico a la otra componente.

## Componente 1 que inicia la componente 2

```
  const equiposJSx = [];
  this.state.equipos.forEach((equipo, index) => {
    equiposJSx.push(
        <div className="card-container" key={this.state.equipos.Equipo}>
          <div className="image-container">
            <img alt="foto" src={this.state.escudos[index].Link}></img>
          </div>
          <div className="card-content">
            <div className="card-title">
              <h3>{equipo.Equipo}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button
            class="btn btn-success"
            onClick={() => {
              this.setState({ isOpen: true });
              this.handleEquipoActual(equipo.Equipo);
              window.location.href('/Plantilla');
              Plantilla.handleEquipo(this.EquipoActual);
            }}               
          >
            ver más
          </button>
        </div>
    );
  });
```

## Componente 2

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Plantilla extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    Equipo: "",
    Jugadores: [],
  };

  componentDidMount() {}
  handleEquipo(string) {
    this.setState({
      Equipo: string,
    });
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const url =
      "http://localhost:8000/api/Jugadores/?search=" + this.state.Equipo;
    console.log(this.state.Equipo);
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    const data = await response.data;

this.setState({ Jugadores: data });

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se puede envolver el botón con el componente `Link`, esto con la finalidad de llamar a las funciones del `Componente uno` al dar click en el vínculo `ver más`:

```
<Link to={`/Plantilla/${equipo.Equipo}`}>
    <button onClick={()=>{
            console.log("function calls...")
    }}>
      Ver más
    </button>
</Link>
```

Además, se especifica al componente `Link` que se envÍan parametros en la `URL`, esto en la propiedad `to`, en este caso el parámetro `equipo.Equipo` que es el que se necesita pasar como `props` al componente `Plantilla`, este proceso se conoce como `Dynamic Routing`:

```
<Link to={`/Plantilla/${equipo.Equipo}`}>
```

Luego, dentro del mismo `Componente 1`, en el método `return`, se tendría que agregar el componente `Route` que va a renderizar el componente `Plantilla` (puede que ya lo tengas), ahí se extrae el parámetro que viene en la propiedad `to` de `Link`, la parte dinámica de la `URL` y se configura `Plantilla` para que reciba la `prop` `equipo`:

```
<Route path="/Plantilla/:equipo" render={({match})=>{
              return <Plantilla equipo={match.params.equipo} />
            }} />
```

Por favor intenta lo siguiente:

#### Componente 1

```
const equiposJSx = [];
  this.state.equipos.forEach((equipo, index) => {
    equiposJSx.push(
        <div className="card-container" key={this.state.equipos.Equipo}>
          <div className="image-container">
            <img alt="foto" src={this.state.escudos[index].Link}></img>
          </div>
          <div className="card-content">
            <div className="card-title">
              <h3>{equipo.Equipo}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Link to={`/Plantilla/${equipo.Equipo}`}>
              <button onClick={()=>{
                console.log("function calls...")
                this.setState({ isOpen: true });
                this.handleEquipoActual(equipo.Equipo);
              }}>
              Ver más</button>
            </Link>
          </div>
          
        </div>
    );
  });
```

---

```
return(
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
                {noticiasJSX}
            </div>
            <Route path="/Plantilla/:equipo" render={({match})=>{
              return <Plantilla equipo={match.params.equipo} />
            }} />                   
        </div>
    );
```

---

#### Componente 2

```
class Plantilla extends Component{
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        loading: true,
        Equipo: "",
        Jugadores: [],
      }
    }
  render(){
    //aqui esta la prop equipo
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <p>Estoy en Plantilla</p>
    )
  }
}
```

---

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.